# CheckWeb Global.asax.cs 'TemplatePagesFeature' does not contain a definition for 'TemplatesAdminRole'

Tags: servicestack

```
Plugins.Add(new TemplatePagesFeature
            {
                MetadataDebugAdminRole = RoleNames.AllowAnyUser, 
                TemplatesAdminRole = RoleNames.AllowAnon,
            });
```

Error   CS0117  'TemplatePagesFeature' does not contain a definition for 'TemplatesAdminRole'   CheckWeb    ..\ServiceStack-master\tests\CheckWeb\Global.asax.cs

Answer (score 0):

[CheckWeb](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/tests/CheckWeb) is a test project in ServiceStack's GitHub Repo which is where I'm assuming where you've got this error. If you've upgraded the dependencies on that project, TemplatePagesFeature has since been [renamed to SharpPagesFeature](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#servicestackscript-rebrand) in the latest v5.5 of ServiceStack which is now:

```
Plugins.Add(new SharpPagesFeature
{
    MetadataDebugAdminRole = RoleNames.AllowAnyUser, 
    ScriptAdminRole = RoleNames.AllowAnon,
});
```

Or you can download the latest master of ServiceStack which has these changes.